# SQL Server : query help on how to find oldest value?

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table called `dbo.files` with a column `created_time` that contain values like:

```
2012-05-21 13:28:56.960
```

This tables has over 138 million rows.

I would like to find the oldest value in the table within the `created_time` column. This would tell me when I first started writing to the table.

What I have tried so far as a test

```
select count(*)
from dbo.files
where created_time < '2010-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

this comes back with `0`

How can I find the oldest value in that column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT min(created_time) 
FROM dbo.Files
```

Comment: thank you!  The oldest turned out to be 2012-06-27.  How would I go about doing a count for the oldest 30 days?  I would be adding in a 'where' to the statement, like:   "select min(created_time) from dbo.files where file_tsuid = '1.2.840.10008.1.2'"

Comment: This is not the best and brightest, but simplest. a subquery: `select COUNT(*) from dbo.Files where DATEDIFF(day, (select min(created_time) from dbo.Files), created_time) <= 30`